# Clearing up understanding Smale's mean value problem for polynomials, which seems easy to disprove

Tags: polynomials

I would like to understand [Smale's mean value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_problem). I am sure I'm misunderstanding it, as my misinterpretation seems easy to disprove. Would anyone be able to help point out what I am missing?

The problem is this: for a given complex polynomial $p$ of degree $d\ge2$ and a complex number $z$, is there a critical point $c$ of $p$ (i.e. $p^\prime (c)=0$ such that

$$\left|\frac{p(z)-p(c)}{z-c}\right| \leq \left|p^{\prime}(z)\right| \, ?$$

I am misunderstanding something, because this seems like an obvious "no". I can choose

$$p(z) = \frac{1}{3}z^3 - (b+c)z^2 +bcz$$

with

$$p^\prime(z)=z^2-2(b+c)+bc = (z-b)(z-c)$$

so that both $b$ and $c$ are critical points, and

$$p(b) = -\frac{2}{3}b^3 \, , \quad p(c) = -\frac{2}{3}c^3$$

Then it's easy to choose $b,c$ (say, $b=1,c=0$) such that

$$\left|\frac{p(b)-p(c)}{b-c}\right| > \left|p^{\prime}(c)\right|=0 $$

What am I misunderstanding here? Though I would expect this problem to be out of reach for me right now, I would at least like to understand it.

Comment: There should be *a* critical point satisfying the inequality, it doesn’t have to hold for all. In your example, choosing $z=b$ the critical point would be $b$ as well, not $c$.

Comment: Ah, of course - it's "for a given $z$", not "for all $z$". Thank you!